# Error in generating dynamic table by fetching data from array in Angular

Tags: angular, html-table

I am trying to generate a dynamic table by getting data from array. Please check the attached image in which there is the array of result which I am getting from API. I am trying to use keys as table headers and values as table data.

I have tried with *ngFor loop and through key value loop but I am not getting anything from array.

Below is the code chunk I am using:

```
<th style="text-align:center" *ngFor="let row of debugQueryData; index as i">{{row}}</th>
```

Moreover, I am getting data correctly in debugQueryData.

How can I write the correct loop to generate dynamic table?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

you can use this code 
`<th *ngFor="let key of objectKeys(debugQueryData)">{{key + ' : ' + debugQueryData[key]}}</th>`

what this code does is to get each key of your object individually then getting then value by passing key to object

Comment: ow sorry my bad   use this `Object.keys()`

Comment: Getting Error -> Cannot read property 'key' of undefined
    at Object.eval

Comment: Am I missing anything else? I have used the code as such but getting error

Comment: this for that I wrote you gets keys of each object inside but your object is in another array first you should loop inside the array, get each object and then again loop inside the object 
``
<ng-container *ngFor="let eachObject of debugQueryData" >
<th *ngFor="let key of objectKeys(eachObject)">{{key + ' : ' + eachObject [key]}}</th>
</ng-container>
``